# Arch Linux on an external HDD GPT-Partitioned

Tags: external-hard-drive, arch-linux, usb-3, gpt

I have an Alienware M14x-R1 and had an Arch Linux System installed on its 750Gb HDD, everything working fine, GPT-partitions (on BIOS, not EFI) and GRUB bootloader.

Then I bought a new Corsair SSD, replaced my old HDD and installed Windows 7 on it for work purposes. I also bought an external HDD casing from SilverStone (Raven RVS02) thats USB 3.0 and I can mount my linux GPT Partitions just fine.

But when I try to boot the ArchLinux system from the USB I get no options on F12 (Chose Boot Disk) for it.

I found [this site](http://www.linlap.com/alienware_m14x) that someone says he could use an OpenSuSe 12 but only on the USB 2.0 port.

So my questuin is, Is there a way I can use Arch Linux (or any other distro, I don't think the distro matters that much) on a GPT-Partitioned external HDD booting from USB 3.0 on a BIOS system?